# object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, controls

I am try to Make a Image Button User control. But When I set image at window Initialize then throw this exception. Here is my Code

EXAM.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ImageButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image x:Name="ButtonImage" Stretch="None"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="0,8,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Button x:Name="ProcestaImageButton" Content="TextBlock" Style="{DynamicResource ImageButton}"/>
```

C# Code.

```
    public ImageSource ButtonImage
    {
        get { return ((this.ProcestaImageButton.Template).FindName("ButtonImage", this.ProcestaImageButton) as Image).Source; }
        set { ((this.ProcestaImageButton.Template).FindName("ButtonImage", this.ProcestaImageButton) as Image).Source = value; }
    }
```

Please tell me where i am wrong.Please Provide me a Example.
Thank`s for Help.

Comment: Use your debugger...set a breakpoint and see which object is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, I'd expand that property out - each statement is rather complicated at the moment. Here's the expanded version:

```
public ImageSource ButtonImage
{
    get
    { 
        var template = ProcestaImageButton.Template
                                .FindName("ButtonImage", ProcestaImageButton);

        var image = template as Image;
        return image.Source;
    }
    set
    {
        var template = ProcestaImageButton.Template
                                .FindName("ButtonImage", ProcestaImageButton);
        var image = template as Image;
        image.Source = value;
    }
}
```

I would then probably extract the common code to a helper property:

```
private Image ProcestaImageButtonImage
{
    get
    {
        var template = ProcestaImageButton.Template
                                FindName("ButtonImage", ProcestaImageButton);

        return template as Image;
    }
}

public ImageSource ButtonImage
{
    get { return ProcestaImageButtonImage.Source; }
    set { ProcestaImageButtonImage.Source = value; }
}
```

Next I would change the `as` to a cast:

```
private Image ProcestaImageButtonImage
{
    get
    {
        var template = ProcestaImageButton.Template
                                .FindName("ButtonImage", ProcestaImageButton);

        return (Image) template;
    }
}

public ImageSource ButtonImage
{
    get { return ProcestaImageButtonImage.Source; }
    set { ProcestaImageButtonImage.Source = value; }
}
```

At this point, you *might* still have a `NullReferenceException` or you *might* have a `InvalidCastException` - and suddenly you have a lot more information about what's wrong.

A cast is better here as you're *always* expecting `FindName` to return an `Image`, aren't you? If it's an error condition for the type conversion to fail, you should use a cast - only use `as` when it's valid for the expression *not* to be of the target type, and you're intending to handle that case separately.

Answer (score 0):

Simple guess but is the image you are adding to your button included in your project (in visual studio) ? And if so, is its "build action" property set to "resource" ?